# Trying to update a row in database via csv file

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, csv, sql-update

Hello i am trying to update one single row in my database. However i am recieving the folling error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' 
(SQL: update `template` set `0` = Module Bro where `template_id` = 0)
```

This is my code:

```
function csvfileupload(Request $req)
 {
if ($req->hasFile('csvfile')) {
    $path = $req->file('csvfile')->getRealPath();
    $data = \Excel::load($path)->get();

    if ($data->count()) {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $arr[] = ['title' => $value->title, 
                      'address' => $value->address,
                      'intro' => $value->intro,
                      'mainbody' => $value->mainbody,
                      'paragraph' => $value->paragraph,
                      'footer' => $value->footer,

                     ];
        }
        if (!empty($arr)) {
            DB::table('template')->where('template_id', 0)->update($arr);

            return "Success";
        }
    }
}
```

What i am trying to achieve is to update the row in database which has the template id 0, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put Your function

> DB::table('template')->where('template_id', 0)->update($arr);

Inside the foreach() loop and remove make $arr 1D array your code inside function look like this

```
if ($req->hasFile('csvfile')) {
    $path = $req->file('csvfile')->getRealPath();
    $data = \Excel::load($path)->get();

    if ($data->count()) {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $arr = ['title' => $value->title, 
                      'address' => $value->address,
                      'intro' => $value->intro,
                      'mainbody' => $value->mainbody,
                      'paragraph' => $value->paragraph,
                      'footer' => $value->footer,

                     ];
            DB::table('template')->where('template_id', 0)->update($arr);
        }
        if (!empty($arr)) {

            return "Success";
        }
    }
}
```